# Consume Soap web Services with ws-security(signature and timestamp) in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, soap, soapui, ws-security

Hi1!

I am consuming a Soap web service, it must include the ws-security header with the signature and timestamp entries. This is my configuration in SoapUI and it works great:

[SoapUI COnfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StHLq.jpg)

I need to do the same with C# in .NET 7 or .NET 6, but I don't know how to create the header and specify these same configuration. I have tried several examples(some very old) but I can't get an answer like in SoapUI and i only get this error:

**System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'WSDoAllReceiver: Request does not contain required Security header'**

Thank you for any suggestions.

Send the signed request in the same way as in SoapUI

Comment: A Soap is XML format and contains namespaces which are schemas used to check the format of the XML.  You error is occurring because you are failing the schema checks.  See following : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp and for signing : https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/NOTE-SOAP-dsig-20010206/

Comment: what is version of .net core you are using?